# Twilio Studio Pay Connector Using CAD

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

I am trying to take payments over the phone using Twilio Studio Pay and Stripe. However the only currency options in the UI are USD, GBP and something else.

I am based in Canada and will need to process payments in CAD.

Is this even possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit the JSON of the Studio Flow and change the currency to cad.

`"currency": "cad"`

Click the Trigger Widget, click `Show Flow JSON`, edit the JSON, save it, and create a new Studio Flow and Select Import From JSON (scroll down to last template).